# List of candidates from different cities

Tags: prolog

I need to get one candidate from each team that competes in the same city. It has to work with N candidates in case I need to add more.

My knowledge base goes like this:

```
%candidate(Name,Team).
candidate(frank,red).
candidate(claire,red).
candidate(garret,blue).
candidate(jackie,yellow).

%runs(City,Team).
runs(buenosAires,red).
runs(buenosAires,blue).
runs(buenosAires,yellow).
runs(santaFe,red).
runs(santaFe,blue).
runs(santaFe,yellow).
```

I´m expecting valid queries like this:

```
set([frank,garret,jackie],buenosAires).
true.

set([claire,garret,jackie],buenosAires).
true.

set([claire,garret,jackie],santaFe).
true.

set(Candidates,City).
Candidates=[claire,garret,jackie]
City=santaFe
```

Comment: How do you decide between `frank` and `claire`?

Comment: It can be any because they re both from the same team

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working?

Comment: I can relate a `candaidate`  with a `city`:

`competes(Candidate,City):- candidate(Candidate,Team), runs(City,Team).`

And I intend to make a `findall`

`set(Candidates,City):- findall(Candidate,competes(Candidate,City),Candidates).`

But im not sure how to say that `City` must be unique

Answer (score 1):

So we want for each city or a given city, to group these people by their team colour, and then select one person from each team.

First, for the sake of convenience, let's add the city data as facts, alternatively you could use a predicate with `setof/3` and `member/2` to generate it. We'll also expand your competes predicate to include the colour as we need to group by it.

```
city(buenosAires).
city(santaFe).

competes(Name, Colour, City) :-
    runs(City, Colour),
    candidate(Name, Colour).
```

Now we can get our sets of team members for each city and grouped by colour

```
teams(Teams, City) :-
    city(City),
    findall(Colour-Name, competes(Name, Colour, City), ColourNames),
    pairs_group_by_key(ColourNames, ColourTeams),
    pairs_values(ColourTeams, Teams).
```

We've got the teams, but candidates are one member from each team,
so let's select them.

```
set(Candidates, City) :-
    teams(Teams, City),
    set_candidates(Teams, Candidates).

set_candidates([], []).
set_candidates([HT|Teams], [HC|Candidates]) :-
    set_candidates(Teams, Candidates),
    member(HC, HT).
```

So your unbound query output will be:

```
?- set(Cs, City).
Cs = [frank, garret, jackie],
City = buenosAires ;
Cs = [claire, garret, jackie],
City = buenosAires ;
Cs = [frank, garret, jackie],
City = santaFe ;
Cs = [claire, garret, jackie],
City = santaFe.
```